# Ogre3D engine based open source game?

Tags: open-source, game-engine, ogre3d

I'm planning to use Ogre3d for 3d rendering to make a game prototype.
Wanted to see how people use it.
Does anybody know open source engine based on Ogre3d that is worth looking at?

I have tried to search at sourceforge, but couldn't anything good.

Thanks

Comment: Why do want to choose Ogre3D? There are other opensource engines available. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365316/3d-engine-comparison

Comment: Simply because I had on semester studying it. So I have the general idea of how to use the engine. Thanks for the link.

Comment: Probably better asked in the Ogre Forums.

Comment: You spent a semester studying it!? Well, then you should know it pretty well... Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ogre Wiki will give you idea of how many people use Ogre3D, and what engines are based it: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Projects+Using+OGRE

I'd say it's definitely been used for enough to be considered both popular and solid.

For engines, there's two open source that seem worth looking at: Yake and jgge, but personally I prefer NeoAxis even though it's not open source.  If open source is a requirement, I would choose MOGRE and choose the other subsystems appropriately for the project, perhaps following http://www.ogre3d.org/addonforums/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=13111&start=0&sid=c999f92704ee1acf2efa91889c619adf.
Ogre3D tends to be used this way rather than for a whole game engine with fixed subsystems.

Comment: Plus their forums are great for support and they have a very active/creative community.